# Minimum number of bits to represent negative number

Tags: arithmetic, integers, computational-mathematics, binary, floating-point

> Minimum number of bits required to represent $(+32)_{base10}$ and  $(-32)_{base10}$ in signed two's compliment form?

My attempt:

$32 = 0100000$ (1st bit $0$ - sign bit as positive)

So to represent $+32$ we need $7$ bits.

-32 = 1100000 (1st bit $1$ - sign bit as negative)

So to represent $-32$ we need $7$ bits.

> But the answer is given as $6$ bits. His reason: one $1$ bit is enough to represent negative number. I am confused. Please clarify here.

Also I have following Questions:

> Can we say number of bits required to represent a negative number is strictly less than (or less than equal to) the number of bits required to represent that corresponding positive number?
>
> How can we generalize the minimum number of bits required to represent a given positive and negative number in signed magnitude representation, signed one's complement notation and signed two's compliment notation.

I know that the minimum number bits will be of order of $\log_2n$. But exactly how much, I am not able to think.

I know that the range of numbers in signed magnitude and signed one's complement is $-(2^{n-1} - 1)$ to $+(2^{n-1} - 1)$, while the range of numbers in signed two's complement representation is $-(2^{n-1})$ to  $+(2^{n-1} - 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

---

-32 = 1100000 (1st bit 1 - sign bit as negative)

So to represent -32 we need 7 bits

---

Let's consider a 6 bit, signed number given to us in a 2's complement representation: 100000

Signed bit is 1, so it's a negative number and we take 2's complement of the remaining bits, 
i.e. subtract 0 from 32, and we get:

-32.

One may also argue that it can correspond to negative 0. But in 2's complement, there is no negative 0 and that's why one can represent one extra number in 2's complement than in 1's complement with the same number of bits.

Hope it helps!